# Как создать вот такой треугольник на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, консоль, символы, рисование

```js
function makeLine(length) {
  var line = "";
  for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
    line += "* "
  }
  return line + "\n";
}

console.log(makeLine(7));
```

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем коде проблема в том, что `*` Вы добавляете только один раз повторяя это `length` раз.   Для того, чтобы кол-во `*` увеличивалось по мере увеличения `i` Вам надо добавить ещё один цикл:

```js
function makeLine(length) {
  var line = "";
  for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      line += "* ";
    }
    line += '\n'; // не забываем про перевод строки
  }
  return line;
}

console.log(makeLine(7));
```

Либо сделать иначе:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  console.log(new Array(i + 1).fill('*').join(''));
}
```

Comment: `i = 1; i < 8` ?)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, та без разницы.. Мне приятнее когда с нуля :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать вашу функцию `makeLine`, она будет возвращать строку из звездочек, если 1, то `*`, если 2, то `* *`, если 3, то `* * *` и т.д.

И потом циклом вывести 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 звездочек

```js
function makeLine(length) {
  let line = '*';
  for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    line += ' *';
  }
  return line;
}


for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  console.log(makeLine(i));
}
```